# How to not allow going to a previous page using the phone back button

Tags: back-button

I have my user in the profile page, and to get there you need to go trough the phone authentication and userinfo gathering. But I don't wanna allow them to go back to this two pages, and when I press the back button on my cellphone it does that, how can I fix it? thanks.

I could do something like when this button is pressed it finishes the app, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Share the relevant code snippets in order to track down the issue

Comment: I wanna do like all the other apps, when this button is pressed it closes the app, its the button that comes with the phone.

Comment: I don't have any code regarding this button, because it is not inside my app